# Colour the most expensive and least expensive observations in R

Tags: r, dplyr

So I have a hourly price series with 168 observations and my goal was to plot them in a chart, where on the x-axis the hours are numbered from 1-168 and on the y-axis the prices. My problem is I want to have the 20 most expensive hours colored in red and the 40 least expensive hours collared in green and the rest should be in blue. This is what I have so far.

```
DF <- read_excel("Downloads/Copy of ee_2020-08-10_ExpV.xls", 
                                        col_types = c("date", "text"))

colnames(DF) <- c("Date", "Prices")
DF <- DF[-1,]

# Convert FB to tbl_time
DF <- as_tbl_time(DF, index = Date)

DF <- filter_time(DF, time_formula = '2020-09-21' ~ '2020-09-27')
```

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example. I need to be able to run your code, otherwise it's really difficult to help you.

Comment: After you `read_excel()`, use `dput(DF)`. Paste the contents into the question so we can run your code and try some things.

Answer (score 0):

Without example data, it is difficult to reproduce your situation and provide appropriate answers. However, here is an example of how you could go about it, by conditionally assigning a factor to your data.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(price = runif(168)*10, hours = 1:168) # Make the dataframe
df <- df %>% mutate(colfac = ifelse(price > sort(price,decreasing = TRUE)[21],1,0)) # Assign 1 to top 20 prices
df <- df %>% mutate(colfac = ifelse(price < sort(price,decreasing = TRUE)[168-40],2,colfac)) # Assign 2 to bottom 40, and 3 to everything else

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = hours, y = price, col = as.factor(colfac))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>